# Moderation strike

Tags: discussion, moderation

There is currently a moderation strike on this site:
[Academia.SE Moderation Strike](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5286/academia-se-moderation-strike)

Which is part of a moderation strike network-wide: [Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an)

Normally this type of key information about AC.SE would be posted in meta and featured on the main site. The community deserves to know when big changes are happening.

But since [SE employees are taking it upon themselves to circumvent the community standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389843/why-is-se-staff-violating-se-policy-by-un-featuring-posts-about-the-strike-on-pe), and [removing the featured tag](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5286/revisions), I thought it would be appropriate to post that information here.

*Note: this was originally posted to the main site since the company's leadership was suppressing meta posts about the strike. The strike has since [finished successfully](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/moderation-strike-is-over?cb=1), and so we have decided to move the post to meta so as to keep it around long-term without introducing confusion on the main site*.

Comment: Full support! Corporate SE must understand that the community is front and center.

Comment: Since I'm the GOAT presently, let me agree with the concerns of the moderators. Large language models, not just ChatGPT, can do a lot of damage here, since they have neither intelligence nor a moral sense.

Comment: "Academia" moderator should know better. Working for free for a for-profit company ( https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosus ) is bound to a lot of suffering.
Hey, wait, the Academia is the same structure that provides the big editors free peer reviews, after making extremely expensive to publish open-access!

Comment: @BryanKrause I know. I have been in the first programmers helping Couchsurfing to grow so big. And I have been burned repeatedly.  See here a long trip, which is the reoad that SE is undergoing:
https://brenontheroad.com/the-end-of-couchsurfing/

Comment: @BryanKrause Have you mods ever used "Academic Freedom" to reject their policy to decide what to say and what not to say on this site ? We are Academia.SE after all.

Comment: @Nobody StackExchange/StackOverflow own this website, it's their property, we have no enforceable right to such freedom here. However, and my fellow mods likely agree with me, I see this site as very useful to fellow academics, and have put a lot of effort towards keeping it that way. The protest is not "bad company is bad!", the protest is "this policy will destroy our community." I feel it is best for the quality of content here, and therefore best for the company, that they listen and change course on this policy.

Comment: Whatever do you mean by "moderation strike?" Do you mean that if I post something that is not ordinarily on the accepted opinion list that it won't get silently deleted?

Comment: @BobaFit - I only see one of your answers that was deleted by a moderator, the first sentence of which was "it's not an answer to your question, but....". If you're referring to comments, yes, it is well known that comments are ephemeral; the answer box and chat are the places to put things that you don't want to be "silently deleted."

Comment: @BobaFit no guarantees, but the elected mods have said they will not do cleanup while on strike. Users can still do what they want and the SE employees can also. That said, I would guess the SE team will have their hands full.

Comment: Right this second, this is the top question on the network hot list, so well done @StrongBad

Comment: This is really a clever way to circumvent it. Joined here in solidarity. +1.

Comment: @Nobody my guess is that if the community votes to close it, others will vote to reopen it. If a CM comes in with a hammer, then there is less we can do.

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for the advice. Our site got three spam posts in 5 hours today. I just left a comment on Meta.SE to warn them SE would become the heaven for the spammers if this thing continues.

Comment: @Nobody I doubt they care. SO has something like half the mods on strike and no bots to cleanup spam.

Comment: Is utilizing the site currently by submitting new questions something that would "cross the picket line" so to speak? I do not want my actions to impede this effort, or call into question my solidarity with those striking. I'm more than happy to log off until this is resolved, if that is meant to be a part of it.

Comment: @ChristopherRodriguez I think posting questions/answers is not part of the strike, only moderation actions (like voting, flagging, review queues, etc)

Comment: @Esther Alright, thanks for the clarity!

Comment: Great move here. SE has been [removing the Hot Meta Posts block on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389886/hot-meta-posts-section-is-no-more) in response to these posts getting hot after being unfeatured. Either they're unaware that they can manually remove posts from that block or they did so deliberately to keep those items out of post histories.

Comment: @gparyani I agree it is not a good look with the timing, but at this point looking at the bug reports on MSE it does not seem this was intentional (see comments like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389886/hot-meta-posts-section-is-no-more#comment1300841_389886 ). Unfeaturing meta posts has been intentional, however.

Comment: To me, the real question is whether a federated open-source alternative exists (i.e. what's the Mastodon to SE's Twitter?), because there's nothing like actual competition to scare a company into doing the right thing.

Comment: @ShernRenTee the open-source alternative exists: [Codidact](https://codidact.com/), founded by users that left during the previous debacle.

Comment: even as non academics i value stackexchange sites as where people help other people, if you want to make people check AI's generated text or something like that do that elsewhere , not here

Comment: @openletter.mousetail.nl -- Excellent idea for a bounty. Someone please write an answer that fully explains the situation! Well worth the bounty and upvotes.

Comment: Note that [Phillipe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe) has just recently posted [GPT on the platform: Data, actions, and outcomes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928) on the network Meta site. I've read it, and recommend anybody else who's interested in some of the reasons for the company's actions, at least among those that they can provide publicly, also read it.

Comment: good to know - following

Comment: "SX/SE own this site" - yes, the legal documents claim they own it. It's not like the millions of people who contributed for free to these sites for over a decade, and are mainly responsible for making the network what it is today, had any real choice in the matter. You can argue that unfair contracts should be disregarded even if valid, and judges sometimes void contracts when they feel enforcing it is against the public interest.

Comment: If anybody else had posted something like this here it would be immediately downvoted, closed and possibly the user reprimanded, for not posting this in meta. So its ok to post things like these when it fits certain narratives? Why not do the same on all stackexchange sites?

Comment: @user13267 I think we might be the only stack with all moderators on strike so it is really important news, regardless of if you support the strike or not. The CMs un-featured the meta post, so we are on uncharted ground here about how to get news out. Finally there are no mods to reprimand me :) If the post gets deleted or I get suspended, so be it.

Comment: Doesn't really justify it

Comment: I do support the strike, but do not support posting questions like this as it will be slippery slope. I believe removing `featured` from the meta posts by staff is vandalism as I commented under Philippe's post on MSE. But we don't need to scope down to that level.

Comment: @user13267: "*Doesn't really justify it"* Well, that's the point about a moderation strike, isn't it? It doesn't matter if a post is justified or appropriate - if moderators and many other users refuse to perform moderation tasks, the post just stays open.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Here's something to think about, if it is some other agenda or cause that I want to raise awareness to, but something the 3 or whatever number of moderators this website has do not agree with, will I be allowed to post something similar here or not? If not why shouldn't I be?

Comment: @user13267: It's not only about the opinion of the three (fromerly four, one resigned recently) moderators of this site, though. There are currently 463 users with at least 3000 reputation on this site and each of them has the right to cast close- and reopen-votes. Five votes suffice to close the question and five reopen-votes are then necessary to reopen it again. As far as I've seen, this post has been closed once so far and very quickly been reopened. The post wouldn't have a chance of staying open if it weren't for hundreds of users who clearly support this, as you call it, "agenda".

Comment: (In fact, after the question was closed it was reopened within less than an hour, and none of the five users who voted to reopen it was a moderator.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Still doesn't make it right, just shows that some people with enough reputation to vote to close or delete support this agenda, and the rest either don't care or don't want to get involved. And it doesn't answer my question either. If I have a cause, a valid cause, that I want to raise awareness to which these people don't agree with, will I be able to post something similar? And if not why shouldn't I be?

Comment: @user13267 my guess is if your cause was "feature' worthy and the CMs suppressed it, a post like this would be acceptable.  My guess is also that your "cause"  would not be important enough to the community to make an exception.

Comment: @user13267: Another thing that would normally be "immediately downvoted, closed and possibly the user reprimanded" would be a long series of discursive, argumentative, and repetitive comments -- but with the moderators on strike, look, they're allowed to stand.

Comment: @StrongBad I see so there are some causes that are important enough that posts like these would be warrented and some not. But only a select few users are special enough who get to decide which is which

Comment: @DanielR.Collins so anyone commenting that they disagree with some agenda being pushed by a certain group of users (and mind you just comments, not a post that belongs on meta but has been forcefully posted on the main site just because certain users think that they are important enough to get away with it) is considered "discursive, argumentative, and repetitive". Got it. That's how it normally happens in academia SE I suppose.

Comment: @user13267 again, if you post your issue on meta, get it featured, get it un-featured by CMs, then it might be reasonable to post on the main site. I also did not think I would get away with it. I thought a CM would either delete or migrate the post and possibly suspend me. Failing that I thought regular users would downvote and close the question. As it stands there are only 5 down votes and 5 votes to close. The community apparently does not think that I have abused the system.

Comment: I think you think this is reasonable because you yourself are needing to do it now. Under different circumstances, had some other user posted something like this before now, i dont think you would have been feeling the same way. And as some one commented above, this question was closed first to be repoened later, just because moderators dont want to do the job they volunteered for, which is move something like this to meta. Just because the company staff removed the featured tab doesn't mean a meta post now belongs on the main site

Comment: as to your comment about closing, someone commented above that the question was closed, just reopened later. And as i replied to it that doesn't justify anything, "just shows that some people with enough reputation to vote to close or delete support this agenda, and the rest either don't care or don't want to get involved."

Comment: @user13267 we have never had a CM remove a feature tag before and we have never been without moderators before. Even ignoring the uniqueness of the situation, as a former moderator here, I don't know what I would do with this question. It is clearly off topic and it is clear the community wants it on the main page. I would probably ask on meta to solicitate opinions about what to do (migrate, delete, historical lock, etc).

Comment: if "It is clearly off topic" it clearly shouldn't have been posted here in the first place. if you were a former moderator I think you very well know that this should have been posted on meta, feature tag or not. And its not like there are no moderators, they just dont want to do what they do normally. so assume a normal day scenario where all the mods were unavailable for a certain period of time. That wouldn't have made posting something like this any more justifiable.

Comment: And the word "community" keeps being thrown out a lot whenever an agenda is being pushed like this on SE. Like i said already, the fact that this post didn't get reclosed or deleted does nothing to justify it. it only shows that a group of people with enough reputation to close/delete want to keep it open, and a lot of the others dont care to get involved. Doesn't mean there aren't many users who disagree with it. I myself would have voted to close if I had enough reputation instead of dragging out the comment section

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There once was a site StackExchange
Which did well-writ answers arrange
A corps of free mods
Would even the odds
Against porn and spam and 'net rage

One day to the website did ride
The Large Language Models blank-eyed
While they did perchance
Write like (noob) humans
They oft [bullshitted](https://undark.org/2023/04/06/chatgpt-isnt-hallucinating-its-bullshitting/) far and wide

At first StackExchange said, "No way!
No AI answer can display
The hard-earned merit
And empathic wit
Of a real human's repartee."

But then the mods heard from on high:
"We now take answers from AI!"
No reason was given
For this fall from 'net heaven
Just orders to change and comply

Receiving such stone-faced rebuff
The mods can but show themselves tough:
Until management
Should cleanly repent
The mods' great lights shall stay snuffed!

Comment: Was this written by a human or AI?

Comment: Either way, it is amazing. If I were StrongBad, I think I'd accept this answer when the time comes....

Comment: It was written by a neural network. Not saying which sort. ;) what do the GPT-detectors think?

Comment: Nobody knows what the GPT detectors think, because all of us stopped using them back in December 2022.

Comment: To be clear, a human brain is also a "neural network", so the above comment is a joke, not an admission that this post was AI-generated.

Comment: I am "NotAMod(tm)" and ZeroGPT thinks "Your Text is Human written - 0% AI GPT*"

Comment: @cag51 - can you please not murder the jokes by explaining them? I know this is academia, the realm of unfunny, but still...

Comment: Normally I would agree, but this page is being visited by SE staff, and I would not want them to mis-interpret the above comment as an admission rather than a joke.

Comment: I feel like an AI would find better rhymes than "arrange / rage" or "management / repent". But maybe that's proof _of_ an AI writing it? I'm genuinely curious what others' experiences are of how strict / loose AI gets with rhymes.

Comment: @Davor I'm baffled that many people find explaining jokes to be murdering them. For me it's the exact opposite, it makes it much better by highlighting all the cleverness in the joke!

Comment: @justhalf - explaining why something is funny instantly makes it not funny anymore. That's why you'll never see a comedian explaining their jokes.

Comment: @justhalf How is telling a joke like skydiving without a parachute? Well, if you have to ex-plane ...

Comment: But you have to ex-plane in order to sky dive, no? =)

Answer (score 221):

Writing an answer in hopes that it helps the algorithm to make this question network famous

---

## Success!

[image]

[image]

---

6/7/23 (after close and reopen of this question):

[image]

Still available on 6/8/23, the puzzling stackexchange post is no longer on front page tho.

6/9/23: No longer on HNQ :c

Comment: Generally, the easiest way for a question to hit Hot Network Questions is when it is well-received (e.g., lots of positive votes) and has multiple well-received answers. I suspect answers posted by community members would be well-received if they explain why they support allowing local communities at Academia.SE and other SE sites to set their own quality standards, or explain why they feel unattributed AI-generated content is contrary to academic ethics and/or the quality of content on this site.

Comment: I came here from the hot network questions, so I believe your efforts have worked

Comment: Given that SE staff is actively unfeaturing posts about the strike, will efforts to keep this on the Hot Network Questions list mean anything?

Comment: Hum, is this another [Here we go again – 
OrangeDog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) towards a Mods cleanup!

Comment: Sadly, this post was briefly closed (by Academia.SE users, not by staff), and so is no longer an HNQ. Even so, it had a good run -- already the 10th-highest-scoring post of all time on this stack.

Comment: @cag51 it's back!

Answer (score 120):

As a brief point in support: This strike isn't just for mods. There tends to be a lot of focus on the moderators, especially for StackOverflow. The strike organizers are occasionally a bit self-important about that, though I don't think our mods for Academia.SE are.

I think this point has been made, but is particularly true here. Upvoting and downvoting are, absent other policies, the primary way the entire SE platform is designed to deal with whether an answer is semantically correct or incorrect. Upvotes are easier to cast than downvotes, however. There are good reasons why the privileges have been set up this way.

As the current status quo without additional AI related policies sits, we are not supposed to close syntactically reasonable questions that are nevertheless semantically incorrect unless they fulfill fairly strict semantic criteria (advertisement, plagiarism, or offensive/harmful content as per the code of conduct).

We experience some negative side effects of these policies here with some frequency, *especially* with the Hot Network Questions queue. We're a small, relatively slow Stack. Syntactically reasonable but semantically incorrect answers are simply very hard for us to collectively bury with downvotes. Furthermore, that kind of aggressive policy strikes me as at least if not more unwelcoming than an extremely rare and appeal-able suspension justified by our current (by company fiat, unenforceable) AI content policy.

I think these conditions are worth emphasizing alongside the original question's, and make the strike particularly worthwhile for Academia.SE. We are a small Stack doing our level best to cultivate a usable Q&A framework for largely non-technical questions. A local policy is a particularly obvious solution for us, and particularly low impact for the rest of network.

Answer (score 81):

I'm posting to point out at this writing that @StrongBad's question is the top network hot post. Plus, thanks to @StrongBad's return, they immediately became the #1 top network asker. So, well done crafting this.

(And it's only secondarily that I accidentally bumped this question from the top of SE Academia and wish to make penance.)

Answer (score 58):

Thanks @StrongBad for bringing this to the main page by these means, an excellent idea! I am very sad that a few people on top are making such bad decisions that are so disruptive for a great community and Ressource that I have been very happy and grateful to have joined and discovered.

Let's hope that this strike has a positive outcome! And as others gave said, non-moderators, join in on the striking!

Answer (score 46):

IMO this is an excellent idea and I think this development has potential to greatly improve the site.

Is there a chance the strike could spread to other sites on the network as well, so that they could benefit from its positive consequences?

Also, I think an even more efficient way to provoke action from SX management would be to popularize competing, alternative sites. It's not 2008 anymore when StackOverflow was the only game in town. Lots of other people have copied the model, even improving the software, their only disadvantage is being dwarfed by SO/SX's pre-existing reputation. I'm sure word of mouth would naturally drive users away from here to better managed sites, but this strike is a great opportunity to accelerate that.

Kind off topic answer, but I'm expecting no downvotes since there is a moderation strike :)

Comment: Indeed, the strike is already active on many sites, though it’s perhaps more visible here since all of our mods are on board. As for alternative sites, there are a few, but it’s hard to build a user base from zero.

Comment: @cag51 StackOverflow itself was built from zero, once. I think there's plenty of users here who would happily use something else if they were only aware of it. My point was that now is a good time to spread knowledge about alternatives to people who don't know about them. Reaching critical mass is also much easier when everyone is interested in alternatives at the same time, as they are now.

Comment: I'm amazed by the number of strikebreakers on this website. I was sure there would be, I wasn't expecting that many and that intense strikebreaking. The rest of SE demonstrates the same trend. If we strike, we must not give up and "get back to work". Having said that, I'm thinking what to do if we loose. And with that in mind, your post comes in really handy. I have never heard of the alternatives to SE. Would you mind listing them in your post please @gomennathan?

Comment: @gomennathan 76 sites have some moderator(s) striking. Including SO, where it's effectively a complete strike. (Only a majority are formally signed on, but SO moderators handled single-digit flags today in aggregate; their average day sees over a thousand flags come in.)

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh One which gets mentioned a lot is https://codidact.com/, which was started in the wake of the previous catastrophic schism between SO the company and the community on their sites, called Monicagate. Monica herself is active on Codidact along with several of the moderators who resigned to protest.

Answer (score 23):

OrangeDog wrote, [Here we go again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper). I can't help but get a feeling, even if remote, that perhaps the approach to the new AI policy was a **smokescreen** for 'another' #purge

Inbtw, I'm not a mod but I participate actively as much as I could. In the process, I get bewildered on some of my answers that are struck down and I couldn't get valid or very good reasons for.

By and large, we all need and want quality contents on SO/SX. May the (AI) strike works well (#fruitful) and *may the mods also reflect on some of their acts*!

PS: there's a mod strike, hence no downvote on this!!!

---

Regarding AI generated content, one danger is truth value and provenance. AI ain't infallible. Indeed, we've seen how they can be: Even more so with research. IMHO, ChatGPT is almost a disaster with academic references. Perplexity AI fare better but still untrustworthy.
[Out-of-scope] My view on generative AI/LLM is summarised in my LinkedIn post: [Digital Pedagogy: Towards a Policy for ChatGPT](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/digital-pedagogy-towards-policy-chatgpt-a-kayode-adesemowo?trk=article-ssr-frontend-pulse_more-articles_related-content-card)

Comment: I do not see a single one of your answers that has been deleted or closed by a mod (or anyone else), so not sure what “striking down” you want us to “reflect on.” But thank you for your support of the strike.

Answer (score 4):

Something that I would like to clarify is while **the AI policy was the final and quite large straw, it is not the sole perpetrator** of this strike. It is also about the general refusal to listen to our feedback. Then, of course, there’s the vote arrows, the AI integrated into the site, the prompt design site, and the removal (and eventual reinstatement) of the data dump.